# I’m using what I want to demonstrate? Inverse of the product equals product of inverses

Tags: real-numbers

I want to prove that the inverse of a product equals the product of inverses, but **I’m not quite sure if to I am using what I want to demonstrate**. If so, *can you explain me a way to avoid this kind of mistakes?*

Thanks for the advice!

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero real numbers. Then

\begin{align}(ab)(ab)^{-1}=1&\implies(b^{-1}a^{-1})[(ab)(ab)^{-1}]= (b^{-1}a^{-1})[1]\\
&\implies[b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b](ab)^{-1}]= (b^{-1}a^{-1})\\
&\implies[b^{-1}(1)b](ab)^{-1}]= b^{-1}a^{-1}\\
&\implies[b^{-1}b](ab)^{-1}]= a^{-1}b^{-1}\\
&\implies[1](ab)^{-1}]= a^{-1}b^{-1}\\
&\implies(ab)^{-1}]= a^{-1}b^{-1}\hspace{1.5mm}._{QED}\end{align}

Comment: Looks good to me. There’s an easier way, though.

Comment: I suggest you give at least a brief justification of each step.  That will help you (and your Readers) be sure you didn't use circular arguments.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Your instincts are good: As written, this proof uses what you want to prove (so is not OK), and arrives at a conclusion we already know. Instead, assume $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ denote the inverses of $a$ and $b$, and use this together with associativity to prove $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = 1$ (and similarly with the factors swapped if your operation is not commutative). This simultaneously shows $ab$ is invertible, and $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: Your proof is fine.  But have you proven that inverses are unique yet?  That is $ac = 1 \iff c = a^{-1}$?  If so this becomes much simpler.   Just show that $(ab)[a^{-1}b^{-1}] =1$ and then because inverses are unique that means $(ab)^{-1}$ *must* equal $a^{-1}b^{-1}$.  So just show $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})$ (by commutivity) $= a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}$ (by associativity) $=a\cdot 1 \cdot a^{-1}$ (def of inv)$=a\cdot a^{-1} = 1$.  That's all.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang " As written, this proof uses what you want to prove"  Are you sure of that?  Can you point out where.  I seriously do *not* think it does.... The OP denotes the inverse of $(ab)$ as $(ab)^{-1}$ and notes by definition of inverses $(ab)(ab)^{-1}=1$.  Then they multiply both sides but the same value.  And from then on out it is simple and *legitimate* simplification of the RHS to get the final result.  The only assumptions are 1)$(ab)$ *has* an inverse and 2) all the axioms of arithmetic (commutivity, associativity, etc)

Comment: FWIW and BTW.  To prove inverses are unique:  Suppose $a$ has $c$ and $d$ as inverses-- that is to say suppose $ac =1$ and $ad = 1$.  Take $ac =1$ and multiply both sides by $d$ to get $dac = d\cdot 1=d$.  A little commutivity and associativity finese and $dac = (da)c =(ad)c =1\cdot c = c$ and therefore it *must* be true that $c =d$ and $a$ has only one unique inverse..... for what its worth and by the way....

Comment: @fleablood Admittedly my comment was hasty. (Particularly, I misread the final line.) The proof does tacitly assume $ab$ is invertible, however, which I construed as part of the conclusion.

Comment: It does tacitly assume $ab$ is invertible but as $a$ and $b$ are presumably invertable, they are non zero so $ab$ is non-zero so $(ab)$ is invertable.... presumably.  We do need to know which axioms and proposition the OP has at their finger tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *not* using what you want to show.

If $a,b \ne 0$ then $ab \ne 0$ and so $(ab)^{-1}$ exists and is equal to *something*. Also $a^{-1},b^{-1}$ and therefore $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ exists as well.

By definition of inverses $(ab)(ab)^{-1} = 1$.

So you haven't assumed anything about what you want to prove yet.

Now you are just multiplying both sides by something.  Nothing wrong with *that*.  You can multiply both sides by anything you want!  So sure you can multiply both sides by $a^{-1}b^{-1}$.  Why not?

So $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)(ab)^{-1} = (b^{-1}a^{-1})\cdot 1 = (b^{-1}a^{-1})$.  There's nothing disputable about that.

And then all you have done is simplify the RHS by simple rules and  the result is that the RHS simplifies to $(ab)^{-1}$.  You are done and you did *not* assume what you wanted to show.

Good job!

......

But there is an easier shorter way.

Note, if $(ab)\cdot M = 1$ then by definition $M$ is $(ab)^{-1}$.

So just show that $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = 1$ (which you are obviously capable of doing).

That means that by definition $(b^{-1}a^{-1})= (ab)^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the exercise this way. I know that for any non-zero real number $x$, there exists an inverse such that $x \cdot x^{-1}=1$. I hadn’t shown yet that inverses are unique, but I’m already added to it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A lot matters an what axioms and definitions of numbers you are using and what order they were presented in.